# Why don't changes made to a global variable in a foreach function callback reflect oustide the callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, foreach

I'm trying to retrieve some documents from mongoDB atlas, below is the code:

```
get('/:page/bucket_names', (req, res) => {
    var page = req.params.page;
    var pageBuckets = [];
    MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, client) => {
        if (err) res.send('error:' + err);
        const db = client.db("cms");
        db.collection(page).find({ $or: [{ type: 'single' }, { type: 'carousel' }, { type: 'freelist' }] }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) res.send('error');
            else {
                result.forEach(el => {
                    pageBuckets.push(el);
                    console.log(pageBuckets) //1
                })
                console.log(pageBuckets)  //2
            }
        })
        client.close();
    })
})
```

The first console.log outputs the updated pageBuckets array but the second console.log outputs an empty array. I'm not able to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hmmmm, not familiar with mongoClient that much. Does the res.send actually terminate the call?

Comment: Loredra,if you're asking whether 'res.send("error:" +err )' actually sends a response and terminates the call then no since I'm not receiving any error message and as i mentioned earlier I'm able to see the output of the 1st console.log and not the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the 2nd console.log was getting executed before the foreach loop  , so fixed it with the below code:

```
result.forEach(el =>{
        pageBuckets.push(el);
          console.log(pageBuckets) //1
      }).then(() =>{
        console.log(pageBuckets); //2
      })
```